# Fix Youtube url RegEx (.NET ReGex engine syntax)

Tags: .net, regex, youtube

I developed an application for my personal use that parses mail messages from Youtube sent to my e-mail account, then it extracts the video url from each message.

I use this application once in a month or two, and the next regular expression was working perfectly for 1~2 years and the last time I used the application:

C# Syntax:

```
Regex urlRegex = new Regex("(content|href)=\"(?<url>(http|https)://www.youtube.com.+watch.+?)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

VB.NET Syntax:

```
Dim urlRegex As New Regex("(content|href)=""(?<url>(http|https)://www.youtube.com.+watch.+?)""", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

However, today I noticed it is not working anymore... something has changed in the template they use to write the body content.

Taking as a example this body content from a message:

https://pastebin.com/VJS6bvMU

This is what it should match in the "url" group name:

```
https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=IGCom2KEH-lFJgHW&amp;u=/watch%3Fv%3DW0ToDn9jXW8%26feature%3Dem-lsp
```

And this is what it currently match:

```
https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=IGCom2KEH-lFJgHW&amp;u=/"><img alt="Youtube Logo" class="header_logo_size" height="30" src="http://www.gstatic.com/youtube/img/branding/youtubelogo/1x/youtubelogo_60.png" border="0" style="display:block"></a> </td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style="max-height:0px; font-size:0; display:none"><hr class="inner-container-width" width="600" style="height:0px; border:none; border-color:transparent; padding:0px; margin:0px"></td></tr><tr><td class="large-section-padding-height" height="20"></td></tr><tr><td><table class="inner-container-width" width="600" align="center" valign="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td><table class="video-spotlight-width" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr style=""><td colspan="3"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=IGCom2KEH-lFJgHW&amp;u=/watch%3Fv%3DW0ToDn9jXW8%26feature%3Dem-lsp" class="nonplayable" style="text-decoration:none; display:block"><table aria-label="Astrid S - Dance Dance Dance (Official Music Video)" class="video-spotlight-width" width="600" align="center" background="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/W0ToDn9jXW8/sddefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEGCIAFEOgC&amp;rs=AMzJL3m-iY1ZW8EiY3QwRalAMfq3atBT-Q&amp;feature=em-lsp" height="338" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center"><tbody><tr style=""><td aria-label="Astrid S - Dance Dance Dance (Official Music Video)"><img src="https://www.gstatic.com/youtube/img/email/transparent_pixel.png" alt="Astrid S - Dance Dance Dance (Official Music Video)" width="600" style="max-height:300px"> </td></tr><tr aria-label="Astrid S - Dance Dance Dance (Official Music Video)" scope="row" style=""><td aria-label="Astrid S - Dance Dance Dance (Official Music Video)" class="footer-font" valign="bottom" width="600" style="color:#fff; text-align:right; font-size:12px"><div style="margin-bottom:8px; margin-right:8px; border-radius:2px; background-color:#E62117; padding:2px 4px; display:inline-block">PREMIERE</div></td></tr></tbody></table></a></td></tr><tr><td><table class="large-section-padding-height" height="16" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td class="large-section-padding-height" height="16"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td><table class="content-container-width" width="560" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed"><tbody><tr><td class="avatar-size" width="32" style="vertical-align:top"><a href=""><img class="avatar-size" src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-YdGE1ZRP_7k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/lTcGNRWN4cc/s88-c-mo/photo.jpg" width="32" border="0" style="display:block; border-radius:50%"> </a></td><td class="small-pad-width" width="16"></td><td><table class="content-container-width" width="540" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed"><tbody><tr><td valign="center"><table class="content-container-width" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout:fixed"><tbody><tr><td style="padding-bottom:4px"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/attribution_link?a=IGCom2KEH-lFJgHW&amp;u=/watch%3Fv%3DW0ToDn9jXW8%26feature%3Dem-lsp
```

( please notice the correct url is matched at the very end of the string. )

How can I fix my current regular expression to match only the url I specified and ignore all that "garbage" at the left?.

PD: I don't need a super hyper complex regex that takes into account domain names variations (eg. youtu.be ) and other things that will not be specified inside any mail message. I also don't want to mess with **HtmlAgilityPack** or similar libraries for this, because it will need much more maintenance/updates when Youtube changes any little thing in the body content.

Comment: This is why it is a better idea to parse HTML with DOM parsers. You might try `(content|href)=\"(?<url>https?://www\.youtube\.com/[^"]*watch[^"]*)\"` until the next "update".

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Tested with around 300 mail messages, It works as expected. Thank you so much!! feel free to publish an answer so I can mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Regex urlRegex = new Regex("(content|href)=\"(?<url>(http|https)://www\.youtube\.com[^\"]+watch[^\"]+)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/z0G9Tf/2)

`[^\"]+` will match one or more characters other than `"` and thus matches will never overflow double quotes. `.+` matches greedily any kind of characters but linebreaks.